# Forloop macro does not work with other macro in condtion

Tags: loops

This is my primative code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\setvalue}[1]{\pgfkeys{/variables, #1}}
\newcommand{\getvalue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\declare}[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /variables/#1.is family,
  /variables/#1.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = ##1}
 }%
}   
\declare{}
\begin{document}
\setvalue{varL = \StrLen{Hellow}}
\newcounter{loop}
\forloop{loop}{1}{\value{loop}< \protect\getvalue{varL}}{{\arabic{loop}}}
\end{document}
```

This is just the start of my bigger macro, but LaTeX does not like this command:

```
\value{loop}< \protect\getvalue{varL}
```

I need to send to \fooloop macro length of the word, which is changeable.

How I can solve the problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: \getvalue{varL} is also integer or not? So why It should not work?

Answer (score 1):

Code should be changed like this:

```
\begin{document}
\StrLen{Hellow}[\varL]
\newcounter{loop}
\forloop{loop}{1}{\value{loop}< \protect\getvalue{varL}}{{\arabic{loop}}}
\end{document}
```

Then it will work.